# Is there a way to make an iframe YouTube browser?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I tried to make a YouTube video searcher using iframe but for some reason it doesn't seem to be loading.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors https://www.<preferredwebsitedomain>.com" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Youtube Browser</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://www.youtube.com/results" method="get" target="iframe">
      <input id="search_query" type="text"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form> 
    <iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: the iframe doesn't load

Comment: did you check the browser console (F12) you should get some error messages that give you some clue

Comment: what is the shortcut for a Mac

Comment: @CharlieZhang also F12 if you use Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you won't be able to :

*"Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."*

The Youtube server `X-Frame-Options` only allows for `sameorigin`.

More info about that subject [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: how do you do that

Comment: @Charlie-Zhang I tried it myself and the Youtube server answered the message I quoted.

Comment: then is there a good solution

Comment: @Charlie-Zhang You could try using AJAX to get the result HTML from Youtube. If it doesn't work (cross domain AJAX requests could be forbidden too), then cURL with PHP would be the safest alternative.